# Unable to get input value using R.path

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am using the popular [reValidation library](https://github.com/25th-floor/revalidation) to validate all my input. I notice they use Ramda to simplify all the function call. I tried to extend their helpers function based on [the example](https://github.com/25th-floor/revalidation/blob/master/example/helpers.js). Here is what I try to achieve

```
import Revalidation from 'revalidation';
import compose from 'ramda/src/compose';
import lte from 'ramda/src/lte';
import path from 'ramda/src/path';

const isValueLTE = len =>
  compose(lte(len), path(['target', 'value']));

const validationRules = {
  quantity: [
    [ isValueLTE(5),
      `Minimum Name length of 5 is required.`
    ],
  ],
};

const Form = ({ revalidation : {form, updateValueAndValidate, updateState, valid, errors = {}, onSubmit} }) =>
  (
  <div className='form'>
    <div className='formGroup'>
      <label>Quantity</label>
      <input
        type='number'
        name="quantity"
        value={form.quantity}
        onChange={updateValueAndValidate}
      />
    </div>
    <button onClick={() => onSubmit(onSubmitCb)}>Submit</button>
  </div>
  )

const EnhancedForm = revalidation(Form);
<EnhancedForm
  initialState={initialState}
  rules={validationRules}
  validateSingle={true}
  validateOnChange={true}
/>
```

the problem is I couldn't get the value input when I use compose to wrap the `lte` and `path`. What is the right way to use it?

Comment: your question is vague, please add more details. Thanks

Comment: Especially, can you supply a sample input for which this fails?

Comment: I have updated my question above

Comment: I think you should `R.flip( lte )`, since I assume you are trying to test if `event.target.value` is less than or equal to the number you give in advance. Normal argument  order of `lte` is in this case `[event.target.value, givenInAdvance]`.

Comment: @fredrik.hjarner if you take a look at their example https://github.com/25th-floor/revalidation/blob/master/example/helpers.js#L15, they use compose and I just want to imitate that function behaviour

Comment: @Muhaimin CS: You are right. I was mistaken and removed my comment :)

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp what is your suggestion? Do you have working demo using their example?

Comment: Flip the argument order of `lte` before even partially applying the function: `const isValueLTE = len => compose(flip(lte)(len), path(['target', 'value']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way currying works with ramda is that you always specify the former arguments in earlier partial applications:

```
lte(1, 2); // returns: true, because 1 is less than or equal to 2
lte(1); // returns something equivalent to: (number) => lte(1, number);
```

So if you'd call `lte(len)`, you get back a function that, when called while feeding it a number `n`, will tell you if `len` is less than or equal to `n`, equivalent to the following 'plain' example:

```
(n) => len <= n
```

In your case however you want a function that tells you whether `n` is less than or equal to `len`, equivalent to the following 'plain' example:

```
(n) => n <= len
```

In other words, you'd want to partially apply `R.lte` with the **second** argument given in advance. It's impossible to call a function with one argument but mark it as the second argument.

One way to manage this situation is using some special value for the first argument that the function interprets as being a *placeholder*, just like [the answer of Scott Sauyet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173588/unable-to-get-input-value-using-r-path/48174966#48174966) already suggests using the `R.__` placeholder.

Another way is to change the argument order of your function so that the arguments you want to fill in in advance come first. For *binary* functions (functions that 2 arguments) the only possible way to change the order is to *flip* the arguments. Ramda [has a function](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flip) for that:

```
const givenInAdvance = 42;
const isLTE42 = R.flip(R.lte)(givenInAdvance);
```

This is a shortcut for explicitly partially applying a binary function where the second argument is given in advance:

```
const givenInAdvance = 42;
const isLTE42 = R.lte(R.__, givenInAdvance);
```

This is in turn equivalent to manually currying `R.lte`:

```
const isLTE42 = (n) => R.lte(n, givenInAdvance)

// equivalent to
const isLTE42 = (n) => n <= givenInAdvance
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Right now I'm using `const isLTE42 = R.lte(R.__, givenInAdvance);` which is just what I need. Still have a lot to familiar myself with FP

Answer (score 1):

Below is a slight change: note that binary operators can be a problem for Ramda's partial application.  `lte(10)` is a function which accepts a value and tells you if 10 is less than or equal to that value.  (It's full signature is `lte(a, b)` returns `a <= b`, and partially applying this works as I mentioned.  But it's still somewhat surprising, and the Ramda team has never found a good solution to this.)  So we can write `lte10 = R.lte(R.__, 10)`, or perhaps more simply use `const lte = a => b => b <= a`.

```
const isValueLTE = len => compose(lte(__, len), path(['target', 'value']));

isValueLTE(10)({target: {value: 7}})  //=> true
isValueLTE(10)({target: {value: 15}}) //=> false
isValueLTE(10)({target: {value: 10}}) //=> true
```

Does this work for your example?

Comment: Thank you sir for your response but I certainly looking at ways they manipulate all ramda function. Take a look at their example

Comment: Did you notice that they flip the arguments [to their function](https://github.com/25th-floor/revalidation/blob/master/example/helpers.js#L14) in the revalidator example?  The comments and answers here are all giving you ways to do this.